# I have this code and I have no idea what is wrong

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: jsonParser
  });
});

$(".btn_val1").click(function() {
  function jsonParser(json) {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data.dt.ld, function(k, v) {
        var title = v.titleContent;
        var img = v.image;
        var txt = v.textContent;
        $('.information_g').append('<p>' + txt + '</p>');
      });
    });
  }
});
```

After I run the script i get this error and I don't know what the problem is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonParser is not defined

Comment: jsonParser is scoped inside the click handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you defined the `jsonParser()` function only in the scope of the `.btn_val1` click handler. It needs to be within scope of your `$.ajax` call.

Also note that your logic is a little odd. You're making an AJAX call to `data.json`, and then in the handler for the `success` of that request you're making the same call again. I'd suggest you remove the `$.getJSON()` call from within `jsonParser()`. Try this:

```js
function jsonParser(data) {
  $.each(data.dt.ld, function(k, v) {
    var title = v.titleContent;
    var img = v.image;
    var txt = v.textContent;
    $('.information_g').append('<p>' + txt + '</p>');       
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: jsonParser
  });
});

$(".btn_val1").click(function() {
  // do something when this button is clicked...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `jsonParser` is inside `$(".btn_val1").click` so it's only accessible after a click. So, you need to move it out of the scope of the click handler.

```
  function jsonParser(json) {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data.dt.ld, function(k, v) {
        var title = v.titleContent;
        var img = v.image;
        var txt = v.textContent;
        $('.information_g').append('<p>' + txt + '</p>');
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to pass funcation before you define it. Try this:

```js
function jsonParser(data) {
  $.each(data.dt.ld, function(k, v) {
    var title = v.titleContent;
    var img = v.image;
    var txt = v.textContent;
    $('.information_g').append('<p>' + txt + '</p>');
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: jsonParser
  });
});

$(".btn_val1").click(function() {
  // should it also call ajax request?
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```